# Can anyone share where I'd find the serial number and year of this Sears & Roebuck bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: Sample serial number]

I've looked everywhere and can't find a serial number on [this Sears bicycle](https://imgur.com/a/cbNtKrV) made in Austria.

[image: bike photo]

Can anyone please help with this? Ultimately I'd like to determine the year it was made. Please ignore the Schwinn manuals. I acquired the photo when I bought the bike but they obviously don't go with it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I don't know if there's any value in finding the serial number, but if you want an estimate of the year you'll need to post some photos.

Comment: If the serial number isn't in the usual place (beneath the bottom bracket) [this guide](https://www.schwinnbikeforum.com/SLDB/serial.htm) might help.  From a quick eyeball it looks like kind of like a 1950's women's Schwinn [Varsity](https://bikehistory.org/bikes/varsity/), though it looks in too good shape to really be that old.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah, I'm really puzzled because the brochures that came with it say "Schwinn" and give a serial number but I can't find it on the bike and the bike has no Schwinn identification anywhere. Furthermore, the brochures say the color is Lemon and 1971. I'm assuming they don't go with it as I'm not awary Schwinn every made bikes for Sears. I'll check out your links....very generous of you. Thank ayou. . I did get it from someone in their 90s who had many New in Box things in Storage. If it is 50s, I wouldn't doubt it. Paid $55.00 for it. LOL. Have a great day.